# Unable to show two or more data rows in the gridview when binding with the List

Tags: c#, asp.net

When the add button is clicked second time, there is supposed to be two lines of data rows in the `GridView` ( the first row is the first click and the second row is the newly added data). However there is only one data row.

```
 List<DonationReceivedItem> drList = new List<DonationReceivedItem>();

 protected void lbnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       DonationReceivedItem temp = new DonationReceivedItem();
                temp.donation = dID;
                temp.productVariant = gvSelectVairant.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
                temp.productQuantity = tbQuantity.Text;
                temp.isDistributed = "0";
                drList.Add(temp);
                 gvNonExpired.DataSource = drList;
                 gvNonExpired.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: the second record will replaced the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the following code:

```
DonationReceivedItem temp = new DonationReceivedItem();
            temp.donation = dID;
            temp.productVariant = gvSelectVairant.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            temp.productQuantity = tbQuantity.Text;
            temp.isDistributed = "0";
            drList.Add(temp);
            gvNonExpired.DataSource = drList;
            gvNonExpired.DataBind();
```

to:

```
DonationReceivedItem temp = new DonationReceivedItem();
            drList = gvNonExpired.DataSource;
            temp.donation = dID;
            temp.productVariant = gvSelectVairant.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            temp.productQuantity = tbQuantity.Text;
            temp.isDistributed = "0";
            drList.Add(temp);
            gvNonExpired.DataSource = drList;
            gvNonExpired.DataBind();
```

See if that makes a difference :)

Because you are creating a new list you are wiping the previous data. First instantiate the list with the old data, then add the new data.

Comment: I've got problem with this line drList = gvNonExpired.DataSource; I cant convert the object